# Want to save image URL in Python Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

This is my model

```
class MenuOptions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

This is my form

```
class MenuOptionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuOptions
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

And this is my view

```
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MenuOptionsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('menu-options')

        else:
            form = MenuOptionsForm()
```

I want to have the custom image field using Django form so that I can use that in the template to upload the image on S3/Google storage. I know how to upload the image on the bucket, and after uploading the image to the storage I want to save only the image_url to the DB, not the image. So it can not be an image_filed in the Django model it has to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `models.CharField` in to a `models.URLField`

Answer (score 1):

```
#settings.py

import os

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_REGION = os.environ.get('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_BUCKET')
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

# models.py

from django_s3_storage.storage import S3Storage
from app.settings import AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

storage = S3Storage(aws_s3_bucket_name=AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

class MenuOptions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=1000, null=True,storage=storage)
```

Comment: Am not looking for how to upload file to the bucket, i know how to do  it, want I want is that I want a custom image upload filed using Django forms so that a template has an upload functionality and also I do not want an image field in the models it has to be a Charfield so that i can add only image URL in the database